# How to use a pipe in Angular Material?

Tags: angular, angular-material

How to use a pipe in Angular Material?
I'd like to fill a placeholder in a mat-select via a pipe.
The pipe I programmed works, but when I try to use it with Angular Material elements it doesn't work.
I can use a Variable to fill the Placeholder, but why does an expression for pipes not work?

```html
<input readonly matInput [matDatepicker]="picker1" placeholder="{{lblStartDatum}}" [(ngModel)]="StartAuswahl" (ngModelChange)="onDateChanged(1)">
```

this works!

```html
<!--input readonly matInput [matDatepicker]="picker1" placeholder="{{TranslatedItems | menuItem:"lblZeitraumVon"}}" [(ngModel)]="StartAuswahl" (ngModelChange)="onDateChanged(1)"-->
```

This does not work.

Answer (score 1):

In my project:

```
value="{{totalProjectCost | currency}}"
```

Make sure to use the double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
[placeholder]="TranslatedItems | menuItem:'lblZeitraumVon'"
```

Comment: placeholder = "{{TranslatedItems| menuItem:'gbStationsauswahl'}}"

Comment: Yeah well I couldn't guess that obviously. Glad I could help anyway, if your issue is resolved be sure to mark it as so !